# window.onfocus doesn't stop firing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome, onfocus

The window.onfocus event does not stop firing in Chrome. It is fine in every other browser. Here is my code:

```
window.onfocus = function() {
  alert('focused');
}
```

What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Technically, popping up an alert removes focus from the window and puts it on the dialog. when you close it, focus returns to the window, triggering the onfocus again. In other words, to fix it, don't do it.

Comment: That is why error logs/debug alerts should never be echoed/alerted, only written to flat files/streams (in JS/FF it is the Console, I guess there is something similar in Chrome)

Comment: Thanks -- interesting that only Chrome does it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the expected behavior because what's happening is that the alert makes the window object loose focus, and after closing the alert the focus is returned to the window object, firing the event again.